# Two rows navbar with collapsible menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Here's the navbar I'm trying to do :
[image]

I've managed to do the menu split in 5 but I'm having trouble with the top pictures (especially the one with the text above it).

What would be the cleanest way to do this design using bootstrap ?

Thanks !

Comment: share you code please?

Comment: Yes here's what I have : https://jsfiddle.net/1rj29ec0/4/

Comment: If you using the bootstrap framework, why is there no bootsrap in your code?

Comment: Does this work for you? https://jsfiddle.net/1rj29ec0/5/ Text is only going to be on some part of the picture.

Comment: Yep this seems good, i'll adapt it for my needs. Thanks. :)